# Numpy function to find indices for overlapping vectors

Tags: python, numpy

It seems like there should be a numpy function for finding the overlap of two vectors, but I can't seem to find it.  Maybe one of you knows it?

The problem is best described with a simple code (below).  I have two sets of data (x1, y1), and (x2, y2), where each x and y are hundreds of elements.  I need to truncate them all so that the domains are the same (i.e. x1 = x2), and y1 represents the appropriate range to go with the new x1, y2 is also truncated to go with the new x2.

```
# x1 and y1 are abscissa and ordinate from some measurement.
x1 = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
y1 = x1**2 # I'm just making some numbers for the ordinate.

# x2 and y2 are abscissa and ordinate from a different measurement, 
# but not over the same exact range.
x2 = array([5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
y2 = sqrt(x2) # And some more numbers that aren't the same.

# And I need to do some math on just the portion where the two measurements overlap.
x3 = array([5,6,7,8,9,10])
y3 = y1[4:10] + y2[:6]

# Is there a simple function that would give me these indices, 
# or do I have to do loops and compare values?
print x1[4:10]
print x2[:6]


# ------------ THE FOLLOWING IS WHAT I WANT TO REPLACE -------------


# Doing loops is really clumsy...

# Check which vector starts lower.
if x1[0] <= x2[0]:
    # Loop through it until you find an index that matches the start of the other.
    for i in range(len(x1)):
        # Here is is.
        if x1[i] == x2[0]:
            # Note the offsets for the new starts of both vectors.
            x1off = i
            x2off = 0
            break
else:
    for i in range(len(x2)):
        if x2[i] == x1[0]:
            x1off = 0
            x2off = i
            break

# Cutoff the beginnings of the vectors as appropriate.
x1 = x1[x1off:]
y1 = y1[x1off:]
x2 = x2[x2off:]
y2 = y2[x2off:]

# Now make the lengths of the vectors be the same.
# See which is longer.
if len(x1) > len(x2):
    # Cut off the longer one to be the same length as the shorter.
    x1 = x1[:len(x2)]
    y1 = y1[:len(x2)]
elif len(x2) > len(x1):
    x2 = x2[:len(x1)]
    y2 = y2[:len(x1)]

# OK, now the domains and ranges for the two (x,y) sets are identical.    
print x1, y1
print x2, y2
```

Thanks!

Comment: `numpy.in1d(x1,x2)` ?  im not sure what your asking or how these things overlap? but this code will give you `[5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Comment: It gives me a vector of True and False.  I then have to go back through the first vector to find the first true and set that as my offset, and then find that same place in the second vector.

Comment: err see the answer (that is likely a better solution) ... I guess it would be `x1[numpy.in1d(x1,x2)]`

Comment: In your example, `y3` does not depend on `y1` or `y2`, so why do you need the subsets of `y1` and `y2`?  Or should this `y3 = x1[4:10]**2 + sqrt(x2[:6])` really be something like `y3 = y1[4:10]**2 + sqrt(y2[:6])`?

Comment: To be specific, x1 and x2 are temperatures.  y1 and y2 are the values measured at those temperatures.  I need to add y1 to y2 where the temperatures are the same.  I'll update the example so this is clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple intersection, you can use [`np.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
In [20]: x1 = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

In [21]: x2 = array([5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])

In [22]: x3 = np.intersect1d(x1, x2)

In [23]: x3
Out[23]: array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

But it looks like you need something different.  As @JoranBeasley suggested in a comment, you can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html), but you need to use it twice:

Here's the data:

```
In [57]: x1
Out[57]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

In [58]: y1
Out[58]: array([  1,   4,   9,  16,  25,  36,  49,  64,  81, 100])

In [59]: x2
Out[59]: array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13])

In [60]: y2
Out[60]: 
array([ 2.23606798,  2.44948974,  2.64575131,  2.82842712,  3.        ,
        3.16227766,  3.31662479,  3.46410162,  3.60555128])
```

Get the subset of the (x1, y1) data:

```
In [61]: mask1 = np.in1d(x1, x2)

In [62]: xx1 = x1[mask1]

In [63]: yy1 = y1[mask1]

In [64]: xx1, yy1
Out[64]: (array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), array([ 25,  36,  49,  64,  81, 100]))
```

Get the subset of the (x2, y2) data.  Note that the order of the arguments to `np.in1d` is now `x2, x1`:

```
In [65]: mask2 = np.in1d(x2, x1)

In [66]: xx2 = x2[mask2]

In [67]: yy2 = y2[mask2]

In [68]: xx2, yy2
Out[68]: 
(array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]),
 array([ 2.23606798,  2.44948974,  2.64575131,  2.82842712,  3.        ,
         3.16227766]))
```

We didn't really have to form `xx2`, because it will be the same as `xx1`.  We can now operate on `yy1` and `yy2`.  E.g.:

```
In [69]: yy1 + yy2
Out[69]: 
array([  27.23606798,   38.44948974,   51.64575131,   66.82842712,
         84.        ,  103.16227766])
```

Comment: Not quite.  It sets the range for the two x-vectors to be the same, but it doesn't give me the same for the y-vectors that go with it.  I've added loops into the question to make this more explicit.